# MyEclipse 2015 WebSphere 6.1 'Multiple problems have occurred' when server starts

Tags: java, ear, myeclipse, websphere-6.1

I have a WebSphere 6.1 server with 3 EARs that I've recently imported and migrated in ME2015. Whenever I start my server, I'm given the following error.

[image: com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandMgr.getCommandMgr(Lcom/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClient;)Lcom/ibm/websphere/management/cmdframework/CommandMgr;]

(Error message that is repeated is: `com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandMgr.getCommandMgr(Lcom/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClient;)Lcom/ibm/websphere/management/cmdframework/CommandMgr;`)

The error seems to be of no consequence, because my server and apps start up and work fine. I would still like to see what the problem is. Google hasn't really yielded any results for me.

Contents of the .log file, same for each occurrence of this error:

```
!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.blue.websphere.core 4 0 2015-06-08 09:20:41.131
!MESSAGE com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandMgr.getCommandMgr(Lcom/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClient;)Lcom/ibm/websphere/management/cmdframework/CommandMgr;
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandMgr.getCommandMgr(Lcom/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClient;)Lcom/ibm/websphere/management/cmdframework/CommandMgr;
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.blue.websphere.admin.proxy.WebSphereAdminClientProxy.getApplicationState(WebSphereAdminClientProxy.java:407)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.blue.websphere.admin.WebsphereAdminFactory$PassThroughProxyHandler.invoke(WebsphereAdminFactory.java:161)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.blue.websphere.admin.WebsphereAdminFactory$PassThroughProxyHandler$1.run(WebsphereAdminFactory.java:127)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.blue.websphere.admin.internal.WebSphereAdminThread.run(WebSphereAdminThread.java:55)
```

Comment: That's a strange error message. Is there anything in the error log (.log file in the .metadata folder of the workspace)? You can view the error log from the Error Log view in MyEclipse for a better format. Also, what does the Servers view show for the server or for the modules deployed on the server?

Comment: @TonyWeddle I updated my question with the contents of the .log file. The Servers view shows the server started, and all modules synchronized, which is true. Everything on the server itself is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your information, this is a bug in the MyEclipse code. I'll raise that. Sorry about the error message but it doesn't affect your code in any way. MyEclipse is just trying to check the start/stop state of the modules that are deployed. Looks like the method signatures changed in later releases of WebSphere.

If you're on the CI stream, that will be the quickest way of getting a fix, though I can't say exactly when that will be.

Comment: I'm not on the CI stream. No rush and no big deal. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: It's been a while and I'm not sure if you're still interested but this problem has been fixed in the MyEclipse CI release (CI 15) which was available from 6th October.

Comment: Excellent. I will look into updating. Thanks for the update Tony!